# Is there a way to change text based on carousel item shown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm using slick.js with a form / questions in each of three slides. Above the slider I have a container with a "Question 1" box. What I want is for the "Question 1" to change to "Question 2" when question 2 is shown and "Question 3" when question 3 is shown.

I tried setting up an .on "afterChange" function which when I console.log (this) does show the correct carousel item but The question numbers are not changing dynamically as I would like

```
HTML: (one question....there are about five more)
```

```js
$(surveySlider).on('afterChange', function(event, slick,
  currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  if ($('.survey-one').is(':visible')) {
    $('#survey-number').text('Question 1')
  }
  if ($('.survey-two').is(':visible')) {
    $('#survey-number').text('Question 2')
  }
  if ($('.survey-three').is(':visible')) {
    $('#survey-number').text('Question 3')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- question number container -->
<div class="survey">
  <p class="survey-question-number" id="survey- 
    number">Question 1</p>
  <!-- WHAT I WANT TO CHANGE BASED ON QUESTION SHOWN
                </div>
                <!-- form -->
  <form id="form">
    <!-- slick slider / form questions -->
    <section class="survey-slider text-dark">
      <!-- inner container for survey -->
      <div class="survey-container">
        <!-- question 1 -->
        <div class="form-group survey-one">
          <p class="survey-title-question">question one</p>
          <label for="a"><input name="questionOne" type="radio" id="a" class="selection" value="A"/><span>A</span>
                                    A</label>
          <label for="b">
                                    <input name="questionOne" type="radio" id="b" class="selection" value="B"/><span>B</span>
                                    B</label>
          <label for="C">
                                    <input name="questionOne" type="radio" id="c" class="selection" value="c"/><span>C</span>
                                    C</label>
          <label for="D">
                                    <input name="questionOne" type="radio" id="D" class="selection" value="Dr"/><span>D</span>
                                   D</label>
        </div>
        <!-- end question 1 -->
      </div>
      <!-- inner container for survey end -->
```

dynamically change question 1, 2, 3 based on question shown in carousel

Comment: Are there multiple elements with `id="survey-number"`? If so, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: Couldn't you grab that from the `currentSlide` object?

Comment: @user7290573. I only have one id = "survey-number". it's above the slide container, I did not want that to slide with the question. thanks! :)

Comment: What you're looking for is custom paging - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55122650/2427237

Comment: @CarlEdwards do you have an example?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Would you use an if else?

Comment: Try running `console.table(currentSlide)` and see what properties you get. I've never used slick up to this point so I don't know off hand.

Comment: @CarlEdwards console shows index of slide 0, 1, 2 so it is working....I guess my next question would be how do you select that index number to target the text I am trying to change?

Comment: If all you want is the current state of the slideshow you may be able to keep it simple and just string interpolate on the index. I'll post an answer in a few. But does that make sense?

Comment: cool! Yea it makes sense...much appreciated :)

Comment: @hendy0817 Okay back with an answer. Check it out and lemme know if everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `afterChange` event passes the `currentSlide` as one of it's parameters, which comes in the form of a number as an index. Instead of performing multiple checks on div visibility you could target the one div and change it's text on each slide iteration, pre-incrementing the zero indexed value:

```
$(surveySlider).on('afterChange',function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  $('#survey-number').text('Question ' + ++currentSlide);
});
```