# Slick slider thumbs not showing in wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slick.js

I'm making a custom WordPress theme with pinegrow editor and I'm using slick slider for my slides (not the WordPress plugin!). Here is the code of one item of my slider with custom dot thumb:

```
<div class="item" data-thumb="images/realmix/products/fresh-energy.png">
    <div class="row productz">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 doesle col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <img src="images/realmix/products/energy-panel.png"> 
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the php code i get from that code snippet from exporting the wordpress theme:

```
<div class="item" data-thumb="images/realmix/products/fresh-energy.png">
    <div class="row productz">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 doesle col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/realmix/products/energy-panel.png"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now the problem is my slider dot images won't get loaded because pinegrow does not convert the data-thumb src into php.

Trying to add the php echo at the data-thumb like this:

```
data-thumb="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>images/realmix/products/fresh-energy.png"
```

does not work when i upload to wordpress, still shows no images
How can i fix that by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i'm following your correctly. I'll update if I am off track.

Maybe try using `get_bloginfo('template_url')` function instead?

```
data-thumb="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url)?>/images/realmix/products/fresh-energy.png"
```

This will go to the immediate child `images` folder in your current theme folder.

---

In relation to your comment on [questions/64405779](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64405779/can-i-use-different-images-for-each-custom-dots-for-my-slick-slider/64408848#64408848) linking to this question, for that script to work with your php, would be as follows...

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item" data-thumb="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/realmix/products/fresh-energy.png">
        <div class="row productz">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 doesle col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                <img src="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/realmix/products/energy-panel.png" alt="" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- next slides here -->
</div>
```

And the script would be...

```
// my slick slider options
const options = {
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  autoplay: true
};

// my slick slider as const object
const mySlider = $('.slider').on('init', function(slick) {

  // set this slider as const for use in set time out
  const slider = this;
    
  // slight delay so init completes render
  setTimeout(function() {

    // dot buttons
    let dots = $('.slick-dots > LI > BUTTON', slider);

    // each dot button function
    $.each(dots, function(i,e) {

      // slide id
      let slide_id = $(this).attr('aria-controls');
      
      // custom dot image
      let dot_img = $('#'+slide_id).data('thumb');
      
      $(this).html('<img src="' + dot_img + '" alt="" />');

    });

  }, 100);


}).slick(options);
```

and the css would be the same from [questions/64405779](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64405779/can-i-use-different-images-for-each-custom-dots-for-my-slick-slider/64408848#64408848)

Comment: thanks for your fast reply! and yes i think you're on the right track. i want to display data-thumb images as php code. But when i paste in your code `<?=get_bloginfo('template_url)?>` it does not recognize it as a php snippet and the php code seems to miss a closing tag somewhere after that line

Comment: Ah I see. That is valid php, must be error further up. Is your file extension `.php`? Can you post a secret gist https://gist.github.com/ of your complete file?

Comment: yes i have a php file. here is my gist:
https://gist.github.com/frimetime/268d2d968f8d23a9eb18e03ee7766eee

Comment: Your php looks good. If its not recognising shorthand php, what IDE are do you use, and what version of PHP? See updated gist https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/8ae3698d0ddf79d6de1681aa7f4f187f (and you will noticed in the gist the php short hand snippets are recognised

Comment: `<?=` short hand echo was enabled by default php [since 5.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), you should be rocking the latest php language level in your IDE https://i.imgur.com/XLM78En.png

Comment: If you can't get `<?=get_bloginfo()?>` shorthand working, then just use `<?php bloginfo(); ?>` instead, see gist https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/23bbce6ce1bc76ac187251ebce04e4c5

Comment: iam using visual studio code 1.50.1 together with pinegrow web editor Version 5.973. how can i check my php version? sry i did not even know that i need php installed locally, since i thought it would come together with pinegrow

Comment: Maybe just use the last gist which should display ok with the php I used. If your are working locally you can add this first in your functions... phpinfo(); , but I don’t this this result is the same as framework settings in your IDE.

Comment: omg it has worked with `<?php bloginfo(); ?>` thank you sooo much! really appreciating this here bro :)

Comment: No worries, try get yourself up to the latest php in your editor. 